# Confusion on differentiability of a function on $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Define, $f:\Bbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}\to \Bbb R$ by $f(x,y)=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$.

Then, partial derivatives are:

$$f_x(x,y)=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}.$$
and
$$f_y(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$
for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0\} $.
Then in the given domain both $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist and are continuous and so $f$ is differentiable. But I can show that $f$ is discontinuous at every point on the negative real axis.

Where is my mistake ? Any help please ?

Comment: That function makes no sense. What is $f(0,1)$?

Comment: The formulas on the right hand side exist for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0\}$, but they give the corresponding partial derivative only if $x\not=0$.  That's where your mistake is.

Comment: You probably mean $\{(0,0)\}$ instead of $\{(0,0\}$.

Comment: Just because the partial derivatives can be (continuously) extended from $\Bbb R^2\setminus(-\infty,0]\times\{0\}$ to $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ doesn't mean that the original function can have its domain of differentiability extended from $\Bbb R^2\setminus(-\infty,0]$ to $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$

Answer (score 1):

Below is the graph of $z=\arctan(y/x)$ (left) and its density plot (right), both using the same coloring scheme.

[image: Plot]

It is evident that $\arctan(y/x)$ cannot be extended to be continuous along the line $x = 0$. Consequently, $f_x$ and $f_y$ are also not defined there.

Well, it is true that each of $f_x$ and $f_y$,

$$ f_x = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \qquad\text{and}\qquad f_y = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, $$

extends to a continuous function on $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. However, this does not necessarily mean that the function $f$ itself has to be extended as a differentiable function on $\Omega$.

(*Remark.* This is an archetypal example where the notion of *closedness* and *exactness* of differential form differs.)